# Visual Studio 2010/2012 Add-in Project Questions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-analysis, visual-studio-addins

I have already created a simple source code analyses tool for C/C++, but I wanted it to be an extension or tool for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 editions. It is written completely in C++. For this reason I created it using "Create an Add-in using Visual C++/ATL" option. And then under "Choose Add-in Options", I have some problems. I don't know which one or ones to select. I want it to have a name and icon under Tools section, but on the other hand, my code analyzer can be used from command line too. If someone can advice me which option(s) to select there I would be glad.

My second question is this, when I have opened a source file in Visual Studio, and if I go to Tools -> MyAddin, and press it, I want it to do its job and analyze the code, and show the results in the output section below.

And my last question is that, if I have a C/C++ project with few files let's say, and if I right-click one of the files, I want to see my add-in and be able to execute the add-in from there, not to go always to Tools -> MyAddin. And also the same thing to work if I right-click the project, then it should analyze the all files and show the problems in the output section.

Please note that I have already created the source code analyzer tool in C++, and I have it as a DLL. I can also use it in Linux from terminal, and if I want I can also create a GUI for it, which I plan to do later. But I'm not that much experienced with Visual Studio, especially about add-ins, that's why I need your help. As you can see my first question is a kind of advice, but I think my second and third questions require some source code. I know that it is very hard for you to give me some help without seeing my code, but if you would help me somehow I would be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 you should consider using Extensions, not Add-Ins. It is a new technology introduced in Visual Studio 2010. Extensions come in form of a VSIX packages and are automatically installed in all applicable versions of Visual Studio. If you are not targeting Visual Studio version prior to 2010, I strongly recommend using extensions.

From this point of view, I will not answer any of your technical questions about Add-Ins. Here are a couple of links to start using extensions instead:

- [Anatomy of a VSIX Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997148%28VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Building and publishing an extension for Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/09/building-and-publishing-an-extension-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
- [VSX FAQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/0be62d3d-84b2-4e17-a306-bcc460621192)
- [Walkthrough: Creating an Options Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195)

Comment: I have heard about VSIX. I also planed to create it. But I thought that first of all I need to have an add-in project, which will create a .dll file for the add-in and then use that file to create the .vsix file. Isn't it like that? Or I can directly use my .dll file of my source code analyzer to create the .vsix file?

Comment: Yes, forget about add-in. You can include any custom files in the VSIX - it's actually just a zipped archive with a manifest and arbitrary contents. There are plenty of features to integrate what you need into VS environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find valuable information on this topic here: [Developing extension packages for Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010/2012 using C# with real-life samples](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0165/)